# Package org.joda.time does not exist

Tags: java, netbeans, import, jodatime

This is the very first time I try to import a third party *.jar into my project. I'm using Netbeans 7.0.1

Besides the usual project structure the following are inside the `Source Packages` folder:

```
Appointments 
|
 - MyDate.java
 - Run.java
 - joda-time-2.0.jar
    - org
      |
       - ...
```

Attempt at importing the Joda Time gives me: **package org.joda.time does not exist**

```
import org.joda.time.*;
```

What am I missing?

Comment: jars don't go in source package. they go in the libraries directory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to add `joda-time-2.0.jar` via project library. (Project + Libraries (Right mouse click) + Add Jar/Folder)

Answer (score 1):

You need to check that "joda-time-2.0.jar" is added to your classpath. If it is then check that it really contains the package mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.joda.org/joda-time/dependency-info.html

Apache Maven

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
  <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
  <version>2.10.13</version>
</dependency>
```